# How to extract the coordinates and names (labels) of a number of locations from a .kmz file in R

Tags: r, coordinates, kml, kmz

I need to extract the coordinates and names (labels) of a number of locations from a .kmz file in R. I already know how to get the latitude and longitudes using the getKMLcoordinates function but I do not know how to get their corresponding names.

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58131/how-to-efficiently-read-a-kml-file-into-r?rq=1) posted by Clay

Answer (score 0):

A KML file is basically a XML file, therefore you could use any XML-package (e.g. [xml2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xml2/)) to access all nodes within your KML-file.
If you provide your file or a snippet of the structure we could help you more specific.